# network interface post-up rule does not always fire

Tags: networking, network-interface, events

I'm running an Ubuntu Server 14.04.5 64-bit on a VMware ESXi server 5.5.0 and the up and post-up rule don't always fire when I use the following config

```
root@tb60C:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.254.4.169
netmask 255.255.254.0
gateway 10.254.4.1
iface eth0 inet6 static
address 2001:x:x:x
netmask 64
gateway 2001:x:x:X
pre-up echo pre:`date` >> /root/log
up echo up:`date` >> /root/log
post-up echo post:`date` >> /root/log
up service ypbind restart
up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Upon reboot, sometimes all events fire, sometimes only pre-up.
When up and post-up don't fire, log file looks like this

```
root@tb60C:~# cat /root/log
pre:Sun Nov 12 15:46:56 EET 2017
```

Despite events not always firing, the interface is always up and configured after reboot.

Where should I look to debug this ?

Comment: I ended up using pre-up event for my simple iptables rule. I can't be bother with this madness.